# framework or method to monitor desktop application in release mode

Tags: c++, cpu-usage

i have desktop application that runes always ( supposed to .. ).
its c++ (Qt) , now i like to get information of CPU , and threads and other information from 
the system while the application is running , basically the information i can see in the
task manager .
this is for me to learn when and how my application has battle necks
is there  such framework or set of functions ?

Comment: What exactly is the specific question here?

Comment: i trying to ask how to run application and in the same time 
get the information from the OS

Comment: You want a performance profiler?

Comment: yes but from within the code , somethning that can compiled with my application and then output it in log file